# Python Bluehost Write To File

Tags: python, file, bluehost

I'm building a software to run on a Bluehost server, and off the server it writes and reads files fine, but on the server it just builds empty files and won't read either, this is a sample of how my code works:

```
File = open(os.getcwd() + '/file.dat', 'wb')
File.write('data')
File.close()
```

It works of the server fine, but not on the server. It creates the file but won't write data to it. What could be the problem?

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory you're running from? Is there an error message?

Comment: I've done every permission arrange there is

Comment: And no there isn't an error message, this is strange...

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the right file?

Try this and see if the print out is what you expect.

```
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()), '/file.dat')
print file_path
```

Comment: Yeah its the same. Like I said, it creates the file and it creates it where it should be, it just won't write to it